# installed 64-bit W7 on Core 2 duo slow pc

Tags: windows-7, performance, cpu, 64-bit

CPU: Intel Core 2 Duo P7350 2.00Ghz
RAM: 3GB

Hi I recently **cleaned** and installed Windows 7 on my 3 year old laptop. And it seems most programs are running incredibly slow when starting up a program or opening a new tab/sub window in the programs etc. Im talking about things like opening an empty tab in Chrome takes like 5 seconds.

It came with a Windows Vista 32 bit preinstalled. And now that I look closer at the processor specs it says: Core2 Duo ***x86***-64. Was i wrong to assume that there would be now slowdown because of an 64-bit OS?

The CPU, GPU, DISK temperature is next under 50 degrees Celsius, which I believe is normal? And there is no noticeable disk IO program running.

Is the computer slower now because i installed W7-64bit? Or is something else the problem?

Comment: Do you have 4 GB of RAM? No? Then no sense installing the 64 bit version. Wipe and reload with the 32 bit version of Windows 7

Comment: are you sure it will help?

Comment: Yup. 64 bit Windows wants to access 64 bit data chunks all the time, double the size of the 32 bit data chunks... so unless you have 4+ gb of ram, it's useless having 64 bit installed